# Count calculation on enum type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQLtable structured like so:

```
file(owner_id int, filename text, status status_type)
```

with status_type defined:

```
create type status_type as enum
(
, 'pending'
   'complete'
);
```

From here, what I would like to achieve is to get the percentage of how many files have the status 'complete' from 'complete'+'pending' collection for the same owner id.
e.g. if i have 10 entries for owner_id=1, 3 with status complete and 7 with status pending then the percentage would be 30%.

Any idea how could I do this in just one SELECT statement, provinding only the owner_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
select pending_count,
       complete_count,
       case 
          when (pending_count + complete_count) = 0 then null 
          else pending_count::decimal / (pending_count + complete_count) 
       end as percentage

from (
  select sum(case when status = 'pending' then 1 end) as pending_count,
         sum(case when status = 'complete' then 1 end) as complete_count
  from file
  where owner_id = 1
) t
```

You can use that to get the percentage for all users as well:

```
select owner_id, 
       pending_count,
       complete_count,
       case 
          when (pending_count + complete_count) = 0 then null 
          else pending_count::decimal / (pending_count + complete_count) 
       end as percentage
from (
  select owner_id, 
         sum(case when status = 'pending' then 1 end) as pending_count,
         sum(case when status = 'complete' then 1 end) as complete_count
  from file
  group by owner_id
) t
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b341/1

Comment: great work here, thank you, that's exactly what i was looking for!